# Play secret of mana or zombies ate my neighbors on wii U?

Tags: wii-u, snes, virtual-console, secret-of-mana, zombies-ate-my-neighbors

I bought *Secret of Mana* and *Zombies Ate My Neighbors* on the Wii U via the older Wii virtual console.

But when I went to play, a message came up that I had to attach a "classic controller" or exit.

So I went and bought the Wii u pro controller on the premise that it is supposed to replace the classic controller for the Wii u.  No change, same message.

So what do I have to do to play *secret of Mana*/*Zombies Ate My Neighbors* on the Wii U, from the Wii virtual console? Has anyone got them to actually work via the Wii U Wii-mote classic controller attachments?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because those games are on the Wii Virtual Console, they require some kind of controller that the Wii (not the Wii U) knows about - the system is operating without access to any of the Wii U specific stuff when you're doing this.

That means you need either a GameCube controller, or a Classic Controller attachment for a Wii Remote - and since a Wii U doesn't have any way to plug in a GameCube controller*, that only leaves the actual Classic Controller.

You can still use the Pro controller for Wii U games that support it, but for Wii content, it can't be done.

While the recently released GameCube Controller Adapter *does* allow you to attach GameCube controllers to your Wii U, the adapter is currently only compatible with Super Smash Bros. for Wii U - it is not supported in Wii mode.

Comment: Update your answer. As of the release of Super Smash Brothers for Wii U Nintendo also released an official adapter so you can use your Gamecube gamepad on Wii U :)